# Rewriting a density in terms of a new variable

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, density-function

I am reading an paper (Lieberman & Resnikoff: Sampling Plans for Inspection by Variables), and I have tried to derive many of the results they state in this paper, but there is one result I struggle a bit with.

They consider the following conditional density of $y$ given $\bar{x}$ and $S$ (definition below the density)

$$f(y|\bar{x},S)=\sqrt{\frac{n}{n-1}}\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{n-1}{2}\right)}{\sqrt{\pi}\Gamma\left(\frac{n-2}{2}\right)}\frac{1}{S}\left[1-\left(\frac{\bar{x}-y}{S}\right)^2\frac{n}{n-1}\right]^{(n-4)/2},$$

where $y$ denotes an observation from a sample $x_1,...,x_n$ of $n$ independent normally distributed numbers where $x_i\sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$. $\bar{x}=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i$ denotes the sample mean, and $S=\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_i-\bar{x})^2}$ is a scaling of the sample standard deviation.

The authors now introduce the following transformation

$$z=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\frac{\bar{x}-y}{S}\sqrt{\frac{n}{n-1}}$$

in which they now arrive at the following density

$$g(z)=\frac{\Gamma(n-2)}{\Gamma\left(\frac{n-2}{2}\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{n-2}{2}\right)}z^{(n/2-1)-1}(1-z)^{(n/2-1)-1},$$

which is recognised as a beta distribution with both parameters equal to $\frac{n-2}{2}$.

I have struggled trying to obtain this density for $z$ when using the transformation. To spare you from a lot of scribbles on paper, the best I have arrived at is the following:

$$\sqrt{\frac{n}{n-1}}\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{n-1}{2}\right)}{\sqrt{\pi}\Gamma\left(\frac{n-2}{2}\right)}2^{n-4}\frac{1}{S}z^{(n-2)/2-1}(1-z)^{(n-2)/2-1}.$$

I achieved the above expression by using the substitution to rewrite $(1-2z)^2=\left(\frac{\bar{x}-y}{S}\right)^2\frac{n}{n-1}$, which led me to be able to rewrite the content in the square brackets

$$\left[1-\left(\frac{\bar{x}-y}{S}\right)^2\frac{n}{n-1}\right]^{(n-4)/2}=[1^2-(1-2z)^2]^{(n-4)/2}=[(2z)(2-2z)]^{(n-4)/2}=2^{n-4}[z(1-z)]^{(n-4)/2}.$$

I know I could also substitute in an expression for $\frac{1}{S}$, but it only seems to make it more complicated.

Furthermore, I know I am missing something, since I have made a change of variables, hence I need to include the Jacobian. This is also causing some confusion, as I'm not sure what the Jacobian would be. It seems to me like I'm going from 3 variables to 1, which makes me unsure of the dimension of the Jacobian matrix.

Any help or hints is highly appreciated!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there supposed to be an $\exp$ before the square brackets in your first expression?

Comment: @JohnBarber No, the expression does not have an $\exp$ term in it. The expression matches with the paper.

Comment: Then I'm confused. Is $y$ bounded or unbounded? Since $y$ is a sample from a normal distribution, it seems like it would be unbounded, in which case I don't see how that distribution could be normalized. Or does the fact that the sample mean and deviation are fixed bound the possible values for $y$?

Comment: Is $y$ necessarily between $\bar{x}-S$ and $\bar{x} + S$?

Comment: You must indeed divide your result by the Jacobian of the transformation, which is $|\partial z/\partial y|$. After this correction, I find - numerically at least - that the prefactors involving the gamma functions are actually the same in your expression and theirs, although I haven't been able to prove it yet.

Comment: @JohnBarber I apologize, I did not specify the constraints on the variables. In the paper, it states that $y\in (-\infty,\infty)$, $S^2\in [0,\infty)$ and $|\frac{\bar{x}-y}{S}|\leq\sqrt{\frac{n-1}{n}}$.

Comment: @JohnBarber I think I get it now. There is only one variable, $y$, since we have conditioned on $\bar{x}$ and $S$. This of course makes the Jacobian a scalar. I think I got confused cause previously I was changing variables where $\bar{x}$ and $S$ were not conditioned on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f_Y(y)$ be the pdf in terms of $y$, and let $f_Z(z)$ be the pdf in terms of $z$. If $y = y(z)$ is a function of $z$, then (as you correctly surmised) you must divide by the Jacobian of the change of variables:
\begin{equation}
f_Z(z) = {\left|\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}\right|}^{-1} f_Y(y(z))
\end{equation}
Here
\begin{equation}
\left|\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}\right| = \frac{1}{2S}\sqrt{\frac{n}{n-1}}
\end{equation}
(Note that since the change of variables is from a single scalar variable $y$ to another single scalar variable $z$, the Jacobian is just a scalar, not a matrix.)
Combining all of this and making the change of variables yields
\begin{equation}
f_Z(z) = 2^{n-3}\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{n-1}{2}\right)}{\sqrt{\pi}\Gamma\left(\frac{n-2}{2}\right)}{\left[z(1-z)\right]}^{(n-4)/2}
\end{equation}
With the help of the [Legendre duplication formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication_theorem#Gamma_function%E2%80%93Legendre_formula) with $z = (n-2)/2$, we can show that the prefactor satisfies:
\begin{equation}
2^{n-3}\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{n-1}{2}\right)}{\sqrt{\pi}\Gamma\left(\frac{n-2}{2}\right)} = \frac{\Gamma(n-2)}{\Gamma{\left(\frac{n-2}{2}\right)}^2}
\end{equation}
This then gives us the exact expression for $g(z)$ you quoted from their paper.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer!